# YQL : Getting unsupported http protocol error

Tags: php, http, curl, yql, http-protocols

When i'm trying to invoke the YQL via cURL i'm getting the following error.

*HTTP Version Not Supported
Description: The web server "engine1.yql.vip.bf1.yahoo.com" is using an unsupported version of the HTTP protocol.*

Following is the code used

```
    // URL
    $URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\"http://www.infibeam.com/Books/search?q=9788179917558\" and xpath=\"//span[@class='infiPrice amount price']/text()\"&format=json";

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;
```

?>

Invoking the same URL from thr browser works fine

> https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where
>   url="http://www.infibeam.com/Books/search?q=9788179917558" and
>   xpath="//span[@class='infiPrice amount price']/text()"&format=json

Can someone please point me what is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably caused because the url you feed to cURL is not valid. You need to prepare / encode the individual values of the query strings for use in a url.

You can do that using [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode):

```
$q = urlencode("select * from html where url=\"http://www.infibeam.com/Books/search?q=9788179917558\" and xpath=\"//span[@class='infiPrice amount price']/text()\"");

$URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q={$q}&format=json";
```

In this case I have only encoded the value of `q` as the `format` does not contain characters that you cannot use in a url, but normally you'd do that for any value you don't know or control.

Comment: Still I could see no response :(

Comment: @Anil Does it work if you use `http` instead of `https` and is the error message the same?

Comment: @Anil There are some additional options you can set / unset for https if you really need it: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 1):

Okay I gottacha .. The problem was with the https.  Used the following snippet for debug

```
if (false === ($data = curl_exec($ch))) {
        die("Eek! Curl error! " . curl_error($ch));
    }
```

Added below code to accept SSL certificates by default.

```
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => "Content-Type:text/xml",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE

    );
```

Complete code is here

```
<?php
    // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // URL
    $q = urlencode("select * from html where url=\"http://www.infibeam.com/Books/search?q=9788179917558\" and xpath=\"//span[@class='infiPrice amount price']/text()\"");
    $URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q={$q}&format=json";

    echo "URL is ".$URL;
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Define curl options in an array
    $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => "Content-Type:text/xml",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE

    );

    //Set options against curl object
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    //Assign execution of curl object to a variable
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo($data);

    //Pass results to the SimpleXMLElement function
    //$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

    echo($data);

    if (false === ($data = curl_exec($ch))) {
        die("Eek! Curl error! " . curl_error($ch));
    }

    if (200 !== (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
        die("Oh dear, no 200 OK?!");
    }

    //Close curl object
            curl_close($ch);
```

?>